# Running a plugin after all fonts are fully loaded, using WebFontLoader

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfont-loader

I have a plugin called slabtext that I want to run ONLY after my fonts are FULLY loaded. I tried the following but It doesn't work (probably an error in the script just before the closing body). Is there a simple way to run the Slabtext script only after the fonts are fully loaded, I already tried $(document).ready(function(), but it doesn't help

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Roboto:300', 'Roboto+Slab:400']
        }
    });
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slabText/2.3/jquery.slabtext.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="mainhead">
        <span class="slabtext">For one night only</span>
        <span class="slabtext">Jackie Mittoo</span>
        <span class="slabtext">with special Studio One guests</span>
        <span class="slabtext">Dillinger &amp; Lone Ranger</span>
    </h1>
...
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        active: function() {
            $('#mainhead').slabText();
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
```

The webFontLoader also adds the class .wf-active to the html element when all the fonts are finished loading, If thats any help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling "google" and "active" in the same WebFont-load() event works for me:

```
<script>
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Roboto:300', 'Roboto+Slab:400']
    },
    active: function() {
      $('#mainhead').slabText();
    }
  });
</script>
```